# Making a web page "viewer"

Tags: php, iframe, curl

I am making a web page viewer that sends requests from the server and outputs them into web page format, allowing the user to browse the web via this "mini web browser", however, I am running into difficulties. I am embedding the content via iFrame. I tried getting the web page content via CURL, but sites like Google gave me errors. And images looked broken because it thought the images were on my server, but actually on Google's. So it's trying to load resources locally. This is being written in PHP. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Insert base tag to load relative paths from other servers, and make sure you send User-Agent and Referer http headers because some sites requires that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not working because the content is probably using relative paths rather than absolute.

Add this at the top of the HTML.

```
<base href="http://www.abc.com/original/path">
```

Or you could check out using wget from the command line, with the -k switch. Which will actually add the full path in where it needs to.  I imagine this will be problematic with poorly formed HTML though.

Comment: How would I implement that into my cURL request?

Comment: cURL does no parsing, you cant implement the wget style.  For the base path thing, when you're printing out the HTML you pulled, you'd just append that string to the top, with the appropriate URL in place of the abc.com example on there.

Comment: Ok, I put in the base tag and now all resources load correctly. However, now I have the issue of links. Whenever I click on a link, it regularly views it, I need to have it view it under the web page viewer as well. So it uses my server's IP the whole time people visit it.

Comment: Thats a lot more complicated.  You'll have to parse out all the links using a regular expression or some HTML parser, then change them, what was abc.com/terms.php would become yoursite.com/getpage.php?url=abc.com/terms.php or something of that nature.

Comment: What about setting all links in the iFrame to be "http://mysite.com/page.php?url=foo.com/pageOnFoo.php"? How would I do that?

Comment: @merc There is a better way to do this by the way, its called a proxy server.  Also, Accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @merc "How would I do that?"  --- See my comment just before you asked that.  Parse out the links, and replace them.  Do a search on SO for html parsing or finding links with a regular expression.

Comment: @merc Also, if the images are now working, its just the same as if they click the links, its going through their server for the images, not yours, so if you are trying to hide people, its only partly working.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Will try to make it so all links in the iFrame go to my site.